# Generator can't exhaust itself

Tags: python, generator

I'm trying to connect two function, one that iterates though directory and find name of the files, send the names to the function that checks are the files older than 30 days and to delete the file if criteria is not met.

I tried for practice to use the generator, and make elegant "flow" from function to function, but it breaks the for loop and function, so it needs new activation of the function.

```
import os
from datetime import datetime,timedelta

PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) + '\folder'


def get_dates(p):
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(p):
        for file in files:
                fullname = path+ '\\'+file
                mtime = os.stat(fullname).st_ctime

                yield (delete_not_needed(fullname, mtime))


def delete_not_needed(fullname, mtime):
    file_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(mtime)
    if datetime.today()-file_time> timedelta(days=30):
        os.remove(fullname)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    next(get_dates(PATH))
```

How could i make this work to connect these functions?

Comment: to exhaust the generator iterate over it in a `for` loop. `next()` just takes the 1st item

Comment: Unrelated, but `+ '\folder'` should probably rather be `+ '/folder'`

Comment: @tobias_k not on windows. should be `os.path.sep` to be cross platform (or just use `pathlib`).

Comment: Use `os.path.join()` to concatenate a directory and subdirectory name.

Comment: `delete_not_needed()` doesn't return anything, what are you going to yield?

Comment: Also, get_dates() is ill-named. Its role is not to get dates, it is to delete old files...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return the filename and then iterate to over generator to remove those files.

```
def delete_not_needed(fullname, mtime):
    file_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(mtime)
    if datetime.today()-file_time> timedelta(days=30):
        return fullname

if __name__ == '__main__':
    files_to_delete = get_dates(PATH)
    for file in files_to_delete:
        if file:
            os.remove(file)
```

Comment: You need to skip over the `None` values that it returns when the file shouldn't be deleted.

Comment: Reusing @waltexwq 's function names was not the best idea. As I pointed out in my comment to the question, `get_dates` is ill named. It didn't get anything, and now it gets old files' names. `detete_not_needed` does not delete anything anymore, but returns a filename or None, depending on its age.

Comment: @Pierre-Antoine, yes as per name perspective they are not good choice, comparing to their work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the generator in a loop:

```
for _ in get_dates(PATH):
    pass
```

This seems like a very unnecessary use of a generator, since it doesn't yield anything. It should just be an ordinary function that calls `delete_not_needed()` in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

I think the general structure of your code is not optimal. I advise that you try to explain in a simple sentence what each function/generator *does*, put this in the docstring, *name* the function accordingly. This will help others (and yourself) understand what exactly you are trying to do.

In your original example, `get_dates` does not get dates, it actually deletes all unneeded files, and yields nothing. So why should it be a generator? A standard function with a loop would do the trick (and you would not need to manually exhaust it).

A generator could be useful in this scenario, though: one that takes a path, and generates only the filenames older than 30 days. Then the caller of this generator chooses what to do with them (in your case, delete them).

```
import os
from datetime import datetime,timedelta

PATH = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'folder')
DELTA_30_DAYS = timedelta(days=30)

def get_old_files(p, age=DELTA_30_DAYS):
    """
    Yields the fullnames of all files in p older than age
    """
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(p):
        for file in files:
                fullname = os.path.join(path, file)
                mtime = os.stat(fullname).st_ctime
                file_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(mtime)
                if datetime.today()-file_time> age:
                    yield fullname

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for fullname in get_old_files(PATH):
        os.remove(fullname)
```

Note that generator is used (as it should) in a loop in the "main" section.

Note also the optional parameter `age` in `get_old_files`, which makes your generator more flexible.

Comment: Thank you , i know- lot of mistakes from my side, naming is the common pitfall for me. I  will use your suggestions.